# How to install Xbox 360 "Optional Media Update"?

Tags: xbox-360

It has been almost a year since I last played on my Xbox, and I want to start viewing some WMV files on it through Windows Home Server. When I tried to play a WMV file it says I need a media update. According to a few websites, I need to get an Xbox live silver or gold account and download the optional media update. I did just that and did a general system update. However, after that I was still unable to play my WMV files. **How can I get my Xbox 360 to download this Optional Media Update?** I'm trying to play some files from http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos which looks to me in HD content.

Comment: "Silver" accounts are just "Free" accounts. So creating one is a simple as signing into your gamertag and pressing the Xbox button and choosing Join Xbox live.(If you don't do this, and create an Xbox live profile without being signed in, this will result in another profile seperate to your original. Also there are media streaming programs out there if you want to use third party programs like Tversity that will convert your files on the go to the Xbox's format.

Comment: Okay, you did that. Then note that some file formats even with the optional media update will not play in the Xbox. Unless your using a streaming program like TVersity.(That I have stopped using because it may or may not have vulnerabilities. Look it up, issue is really being online with a streaming program. Shouldn't bother many.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had to go to Game Marketplace -> Explore COntent -> All Games -> Browse All Games -> O -> Optional Media Update. From here I was able to download Optional Media Update as an addon and run my files.

Comment: Keep in mind if you have previously downloaded this file elsewhere(previous Xbox, mates Xbox, etc.) It will not be registered to the Xbox and most likely won't work offline. To fix this, download it with a profile that hasn't downloaded it or re-register your content to your current Xbox.

Answer (score 10):

I just did this yesterday.  When you try to play an unsupported video, it will prompt you asking if you want to download the optional media update.  If you go through the menu screens, it will then download and install it.

Comment: This isn't the case for me.

Comment: This also did not work for me. Downloading the media update manually seemed to work just fine...

Answer (score 6):

Connect to live. Try to play a divx under video library from portable device (USB). It will give you an error code and then ask if you want to download the update and take you directly there. I did this with a modded xbox and did not get banned. Otherwise I never connect to live but this is the only way to get the optional media update

Answer (score 6):

As of 2014, this is now in "Add Ons". Searching in "Games" will not find it. Go to Add Ons, browse "O", find "Optional Media Update".

Answer (score 3):

I just did this (2013), it was really easy.

Just go to the "Search Games" option where you would manually type in the game name, and instead type in the word "optional" (or really just type OPT and it auto-finishes it for you).

There's a 2008 & 2011 version of the Optional Media Update.  Download the 2011 version, it is 100% completely free -- I did not need a Silver or Gold membership to download it.  After that you're all set, and you can play MP4s on your 360.

Comment: If you didn't have an account, how did you connect?